64-bit PChar pointer arithmetic gives range check error
I'm tracing a bug deep in 3rd party code, where the statement
 fStringLen := Str - fToIdent;

gives a run-time error, with:

Str is a PChar private function parameter, it is '' at this moment
(Initially not empty but Inc(Str) executed till the end of a loop)
fStringlen is an integer private property, value 0
fToIdent is a PChar private property, it shows nil {%0} in the inspector window:


It's unclear at this moment whether anything Tracing all occurrences it looks like nothing has been done to the
fToIndent PChar property  (it does not have a setter that I can put a breakpoint on), or if  and this is just the initial state after creation of its object.
There is a somewhat older 32-bit version of our software with an older version of the 3rd party software, but where that piece of code is identical. The values are the same if I run the code, but then there is no range check error.
FWIW, this is the code, see last statement :
    function TdaSynHighlighterSQL.HashKey(Str: PChar): Integer;
    // called with Str = 'absolute'

      function GetOrd: Integer;
      begin
        case Str^ of
          '_': Result := 1;
          'a'..'z': Result := 2 + Ord(Str^) - Ord('a');
          'A'..'Z': Result := 2 + Ord(Str^) - Ord('A');
          '@':
            if fDialect in [sqlMSSQL7, sqlMSSQL2K] then
              Result := 24
            else
              Result := 0;
          else Result := 0;
        end;
      end;

    begin
      Result := 0;
      while IsIdentChar(Str^) do  // Always true until Str=''
      begin
        Result := (2 * Result + GetOrd) and $FFFFFF;
        inc(Str);
      end;
      Result := Result and $FF; // 255
      fStringLen := Str - fToIdent;
    end;

How to best fix this?
I find it strange that this code still would not be 64-bit proof

if fToIdent is nil and Str points to the end of the given string and that string is allocated at a high memory position then that could trigger that range error. IMHO should fToIdent point to the start of the string to calculate the length.

Ask your self how you can fit a 64 bit value into a 32 variable and you'll see the problem

David Heffernan's comment pointed in the right direction:
fToIdent does not get initialized because the function IdentKind() that sets it was not called yet (not the error).
In the 32-bit version fStringLen becomes 245556086 if fToIdent=nil and that fits in an integer.
In the 64-bit version fStringLen becomes 1513182692840 if fToIdent=nil and that does not fit in the integer.
We made a quick patch in the source:
// fStringLen := Str - fToIdent;
// Prevent rangecheck error
if (fToIdent=nil) then
  fStringLen := 0
else
  fStringLen := Str - fToIdent;
 

BTW. This was in ReportBuilder 22.03, in the support forum I got this answer:

The version of SynEdit used in ReportBuilder has been highly customized and was not originally intended for 64 bit applications. We have converted it to do so however occasionally an issue will arise that slipped through the cracks.
There is now a patch available for RB 22.04 that addresses this issue.

We have not yet updated to 22.04 so I don't know how they patched it.

The problem is caused by the use of while loop.At the time your fStringLen := Str - fToIdent; executed it is already pointing to memory past the length of your string which then causes the range check error.
Consider this simple while loop example where I have simple integer for control value.
while I < 10 do
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Add('Value of I in current loop cycle is ' +IntToStr(I));
  Inc(I,1);
end;
Memo1.Lines.Add('Value of I after loop is: '+IntToStr(I));

You might expect that value of control variable I would be 9 after the while loop ends but it is not. In fact it is 10. Why is that.
That is because whole loop is checking the value of control variable before the start of each cycle. But I have increased the value of control variable past the desired range in last loop cycle.
So you might want to calculate your fStringLen inside your loop before increasing the value of Str.
while IsIdentChar(Str^) do  // Always true until Str=''
begin
  Result := (2 * Result + GetOrd) and $FFFFFF;
  fStringLen := Str - fToIdent;
  inc(Str);
end;

This will however lead to fStringLen  being updated for each character in your string.
But if you want to avoid that and still calculate fStringLen after the loop make you decrease the value of Str by one before so that it show to the position of the last character in your string.
PS: I don't understand why your code causes range exception only in 64 build. It should have caused the range exception in 32 bit build as well.

Moving the fStringLen calculation moves the error location only ;-)
